# Scheduled Slack Message with Current Date

Tags: slack, slack-api, slack-commands

I want to send a message in a slack group every day at 9 PM UTC.
This is for getting feedbacks from everyday meetings held.

The message should contain a text like -"Daily Feedback" along with current day

Example :

Date: 29th April 2021.

Feedback Thread.

Answer (score 0):

The [chat.scheduleMessage](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.scheduleMessage) doesn't support recurrence out of the box like you're describing, so you have three options

- Set a [cron](https://crontab.guru/) on your server that calls the [chat.postMessage](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage) endpoint at 9PM UTC (that would be `0 21 * * *`)
- You could alternatively call [chat.scheduleMessage](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.scheduleMessage) on a cron, but that feels a bit overengineered to me. Better to just have the cron fire the real message.
- You could not write any code at all and use [Workflow Builder](https://slack.com/intl/en-ie/help/articles/360053571454-Set-up-a-workflow-in-Slack), but that assumes you're using a paid workspace. The previous two options will work fine on a free workspace.